# Object's projection in material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Wanted to ask if there any way to project an object onto a surface using nodes or anything else?
As Shrinkwrap does it, but I need it in my nodes to make a shader.

Comment: In theory you could bake the vector displacement of the model and use that. In practice: Blender can't do that yet, you'll need another program to bake and re-import the map. It won't work for animation, it will be very tedious to make it perfect. Unless someone with more knowledge about OSL than me comes along and saves the day, I'm afraid that's a very hard thing to do.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz  I've tried tracing a ray down the normal with OSL .. I can get the heights to show up OK.. but, frustratingly, displacement will not respond. I can only imagine it's all happening at the wrong place in the pipeline?

Comment: I remember having the displacement trouble myself with an osl generated texture, that was a long time ago so if they still haven't fixed it, it must be pretty hard.